# Get required value from an object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am just trying to get an `ID` from object.But am getting `undefined` for user id  here.

```
var userId = _.uniq(_.pluck(userDetails,'ID'));
```

My `userDetails` object will be like this

```
0:object
  $$haskKey:"object:197"
  name:"jonh"
  ID:"1038"
```

I should use  `_.uniq` and  `_.pluck` here.

Comment: @downvoter can you please explain the reason to downvote my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply

```
var userId = userDetails.ID;
```

```js
var myObj = [{"name":"jonh",
  "ID":"1038"}];
var MyId = _.uniq(_.pluck(myObj,'ID'));
console.log(MyId);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: check updated answer, it should be an array to use _.uniq